# How to acces the type of a place (widget-pane-link) form Google Maps from python using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

[image: Google Maps type of place tag]

I am trying to get the tag **American Restaurant** under the Name El Merendero and the review of 4.1 using python and beautiful soup but I was not able to enter in . Any hint on how to find this google maps category ?

what I got is this text with some Javascript error I guess :

> Enable JavaScript to see Google Maps.

My code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Query = " Restaurant el merendero "

durl= "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=%s" % Query
page = requests.get(durl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

unicode_str = soup.decode("utf8")
encoded_str = unicode_str.encode("ascii",'ignore')
news_soup = BeautifulSoup(encoded_str, "html.parser")
a_text = news_soup.find_all('div')
print(a_text)
```

Comment: Could you please post the code that you have so far

Comment: Yeah, it's done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that google map is rendered as a single page app with Angular (I believe).

BeautifulSoup is unable to execute Javascript so you'd need execute the Javascript code (eg: with [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) or [Splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) or any headless browser) before it can actually view and crawl the rendered HTML.

See this repository which holds an example of what you are trying to achieve: https://github.com/registerguard/spa_scraper

You can witness what I'm saying by disabling Javascript in your browser and going to google maps.